# Conversion of hexadecimal string to string

Tags: c#, strings, serialization

Given a C# string which is a set of hexadecimal numbers such as:

```
string HexString = "202048656c6c6f20576f726c64313233212020";
```

Where those hexadecimal numbers represent the ASCII text:

```
"  Hello World123!  "
```

I need to convert the `HexString` to a String and I have the following code which works, but looks so excessive!

```
string HexStringToString(string HexString) {
    string stringValue = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < HexString.Length / 2; i++) {
        string hexChar = HexString.Substring(i * 2, 2);
        int hexValue = Convert.ToInt32(hexChar, 16);
        stringValue += Char.ConvertFromUtf32(hexValue);
    }
    return stringValue;
}
```

Am I missing some elegant method?

Comment: This method should be `static` as it appears that it doesn't access any class instance data. Further, it looks like an excellent candidate to be an extension method (simply change the parameter to read `this string HexString` after making the method `static`).

Comment: just because a method doesnt access any class instance data it has to be static, what if it was written in a big project and later you want to add more functionality/flexibility? How would you inherit from the class and override it?

Comment: Is there any way you can get those values separated by some kind of separating character like a space? If so then you can use split for some magic. Otherwise the performance will suffer if you want to use a linq-esque solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The method does two different things and thus should be split in two:

1. Interpret a hex string as a sequence of bytes. You can find many possible implementations at [How do you convert Byte Array to Hexadecimal String, and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa).

   Yours has quadratic runtime (due to the string concatenation pattern RobH noted) and creates a new string object for each byte.

   Keeping it similar to yours, but reducing it to linear runtime:

   ```
   public static byte[] HexStringToBytes(string hexString)
   {
       if(hexString == null)
           throw new ArgumentNullException("hexString");
       if(hexString.Length % 2 != 0)
           throw new ArgumentException("hexString must have an even length", "hexString");
       var bytes = new byte[hexString.Length / 2];
       for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
       {
           string currentHex = hexString.Substring(i * 2, 2);
           bytes[i] = Convert.ToByte(currentHex, 16);
       }
       return bytes;
   }
   ```

   This code is still relatively slow, creating a new substring for each byte and using `Convert.ToByte`, but I'd only complicate that after benchmarking revealed this as relevant cost.
2. Interpret the sequence of bytes as an ISO-8859-1 encoded string. This is equivalent to your code, since the first 256 code-points in Unicode match the ISO-8859-1 single-byte encoding.

   I'd use:

   ```
   Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetString(bytes)
   ```

   You should consider using UTF-8 instead, so you can support any Unicode code-point and not just those common in western Europe.

Comment: I think this answer is better than mine - I certainly think you're right about splitting it into two methods. Good point about being explicit about the encoding as well.

Comment: ANSI Windows-1252 encoding is favored over ISO-8859-1.

Answer (score 12):

I don't think there is a built-in method. Yours is pretty good but we could make some improvements:

- Parameters should be camelCase => hexString.
- You should favour `StringBuilder` when building up strings.
- You should step through the string in increments of 2 to cut down on the maths.
- You should validate the argument.
- You should prefer `var` when the type is obvious.

Result of those points:

```
string HexStringToString(string hexString) 
{
    if (hexString == null || (hexString.Length & 1) == 1) 
    {
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (var i = 0; i < hexString.Length; i += 2) {
        var hexChar = hexString.Substring(i, 2);
        sb.Append((char)Convert.ToByte(hexChar, 16));
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate your improvements. My code is typically just reviewed by me, so I don't get much good advice! I will have to start using StringBuilder as it really is not in my repertoire (I have a C/assy background). As far as the math of i+2 vs i*2, I would "assume" the compiler sees *2 as a shift and no real multiplication. (I totally misunderstand var.) In this case the hexString is known to consist of pairs of hex digits on entry; however, to make it reusable, definitely validate. As to camelCase, I have to admit my functions, properties, methods and parameters are ALLOverthePlace!

Comment: @frog_jr - I simplified the maths to make it easier to read. I don't generally worry about perf unless I see a problem when profiling.

Comment: This solution is ok for ASCII, but is bad for UTF8 encoded HEX

Comment: To elaborate, If you try to convert Hex string `3C 6E 61 6D 65 3E D0 9D D0 B5 D0 BC D0 B0 D1 9A D0 B0 3C 2F 6E 61 6D 65 3E` wich represent my Cyrillic name within tag name `<name>Немања</name>` you will get garbage like`<name>ÐÐµÐ¼Ð°ÑÐ°</name>`instead, and that's all because you are grouping characters by 2.

Comment: @nemke - I realized what you meant so I deleted my comment. The OP specifically mentions ASCII but you are of course correct that it doesn't scale to other character encodings.

Comment: @RobH Yup, the OP is for ASCII.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to depart from the other answers and focus on this bit:

> Am I missing some elegant method?

Do you consider Regex to be elegant? You could reduce the amount of code required at the cost of performance. Take the following Regex expression:

```
(?<=\G..)(?!$)
```

Broken down:

```
(?<=            # Look-behind that won't actually be captured
    \G          # Zero-width assertion
      ..        # Match exactly two characters
        )(?!$)  # Do not match an empty group at the end of the string
```

Then it's just a matter of transforming the string array into a collection of characters and joining them all back together. Using Linq's `Select` and the `string.Join` method, this can be done quickly.

A short implementation may look like:

```
string HexStringToString(string hexString)
{
    string[] hexValues = Regex.Split(hexString, "(?<=\\G..)(?!$)");
    var characters = hexValues.Select(hex => (char)Convert.ToByte(hex, 16));
    return string.Join(string.Empty, characters);
}
```

Elegant? Sure. You could even do it all on a single line:

```
string HexStringToString(string hexString)
{
    return string.Join("", Regex.Split(hexString, "(?<=\\G..)(?!$)").Select(x => (char)Convert.ToByte(x, 16)));
}
```

But elegance is never more valuable than readability and maintainability.

---

As [@CodesInChaos](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/1482/codesinchaos) said, your method is doing multiple things and should be split apart. I would even break out the functionality of separating a string into its own method, perhaps as an extension method off of the `String` class.

Comment: This is much better 

string HexStringToString(string hexString) => string.Join("", Regex.Split(hexString, "(?<=\\G..)(?!$)").Select(x => (char)Convert.ToByte(x, 16)));

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for elegant you can consider the functional paradigm. Here I have added a function SelectPair which maps 2 elements of an IEnumerable to a single element; allowing the 2 characters of the hex string to be extracted together.

The main code then reduces to

```
static string HexStringToString(string hexString) 
{
    return 
        String.Join(
            "",
            hexString
                .ToCharArray()
                .SelectPair(
                    (ch1,ch2) => ch1.ToString() + ch2)
                .Select(
                    hexChar => (char) Convert.ToByte(hexChar, 16)));
}
```

SelectPair is an extension method, which can be reused elsewhere.

```
public static class LinqExt
{
    public 
    static
    IEnumerable<TResult>
    SelectPair<TSource, TResult>(
        this
        IEnumerable<TSource>                list,
        Func<TSource,TSource,TResult>       onPair)
    {
        var odd   = default(TSource);
        var isOdd = true;

        foreach(var item in list)
        {
            if (isOdd)
            {
                odd = item;
            }
            else
            {
                yield return onPair(odd, item);
            }

            isOdd = !isOdd;
        }
    }           
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I like the original code best.  I don't know of a better way than iterating through the string and the original code is actually pretty readable and likely no slower than any of the other options.